# How to style Bootstrap dropdown-menu to be full page width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to modify the dropdown-menu provided in Bootstrap, using the navbar-fixed-top, to appear on hover not vertically but horizontally `li { display: inline-block }` (that's easy), but so I need the actual `ul.dropdown-menu` to stretch the full width of the page. I can't seem to figure it out.

Don't give me a megamenu plugin or anything, please, just how can I fix it to stretch the width of the whole page? (not the page container either, the window)

Will probably need to wrap another element too, actually, as the ul needs to be centered.

So does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: Figured it out (like 5 minutes after posting this) and with no added elements:

```css
.nav { margin-bottom: 0; }
.dropdown { position: static; }
.dropdown-menu { width: 100%; text-align: center; }
.dropdown-menu>li { display: inline-block; }
```

and there you have it!

Comment: please share all the relevant code and put it in a [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can play with it

Answer (score 41):

First you shouldn't wrap the navbar component in a div.container then update the css with the following Code:

```
.nav > li.dropdown.open {
    position: static;
}
.nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
    display:table; width: 100%; text-align: center; left:0; right:0;
}
.dropdown-menu>li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

check the demo here http://www.bootply.com/8EgGsi4F7w

Comment: If I use this, i can't make the menu open on hover (vs. click). It just shrinks the menu back to default size.

Comment: @hesham is there any possibility for container.

Comment: @IlyasDattoo Do you mean wrapping the menu in container? or what do you mean ?

Comment: @heshamelghndour Yeah i am wrapping the navbar in container.

Comment: Yes i got a solution.
Just changing the dropdown position to `fixed` and set the `top` value as you want :) 
Check the demo http://www.bootply.com/Djig4iuQlg

Comment: @heshamelghndour I also got a solution. By giving position `relative` to `.container`.

Comment: I think you'll favor these results too -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147186/how-to-restrict-width-of-bootstrap-3-dropdown-menu-in-navbar

Answer (score 24):

```
<li class="dropdown open" style="position: initial;">
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 100%;">
```

just use the position: initial in the main **li(dropdown)** of your nav and in the child ul  dropdown-menu set width 100%

[image]

Comment: A nice approach!

Comment: simple, efficient .. very nice.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-design-full-width-dropdown-navbar-using-bootstrap/) the alternative that worked for me.

I just tried option 2. The key is:

> Adding class position-static along with (the) dropdown class, which is the parent class of dropdown-menu as follows:
>
> `<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">`

Credit to its author: VigneshKannan3 from GeeksforGeeks

---

It looks like [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49659512/5802289) has the same approach.

Answer (score -1):

[Check this](https://codepen.io/danielmdesigns/pen/QbgYKa)

```css
.nav > li.dropdown.open {
  position: static;
}

.nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
  display: table;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu > li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown-menu > li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="navbar-brand">Blackcat</div>
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".btnCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse btnCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Artist <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Rich</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shay</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jose</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Marie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Simon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jamie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Andrew</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teddie</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- end container -->
</div>
<!-- end navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top -->

<!-- container -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p>Site content here...</p>
  </div>
  <!-- End row -->
</div>
<!-- End container -->
```

Comment: Adding a brief explanation of *why* the code above answers the question asked, will be more useful to others, than just code alone.