# How to make width of dropdown-menu equal to width of it's parent in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a dropdown in bootstrap 4. I placed the *dropdown-toggle button* and *dropdown-menu* in a *div element with class="container"* I want the dropdown toggle and dropdown-menu to take full width of its parent element. I wrote this code for that

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <button class="dropdown-toggle btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown">
      dropdown
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a href="" class="dropdown-item">one</a>
      <a href="" class="dropdown-item">two</a>
      <a href="" class="dropdown-item">three</a>
      <a href="" class="dropdown-item">four</a>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

The dropdown-toggle button takes up the full width of it's parent div. But, When I clicked on dropdown-toggle button I observed that the dropdown-menu is'nt taking full width. I want the width of drop dropdown-menu to be equal to it's parent width how can I do that? *(I tried to use width:inherit; property but that did'nt worked properly)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dropdown-menu has `position:absolute` property. So, adding `width:100%;` will make the dropdown-menu to take full width of the page instead of taking full width of container. To make the dropdown-menu take the width of it's parent element make the parent element's positioning relative. To solve the problem first Add `class="position-relative"` attribute to the parent element of dropdown-menu. Now add w-100 to the class attribute of the dropdown-menu div.

```
<div class="container position-relative">
<button class="dropdown-toggle btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown">
  dropdown
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu w-100">
  <a href="" class="dropdown-item">one</a>
  <a href="" class="dropdown-item">two</a>
  <a href="" class="dropdown-item">three</a>
  <a href="" class="dropdown-item">four</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, this principle will work with stuff outside of bootstrap too if you code the CSS styles yourself. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You don't need extra CSS. Just use the `display="static"` [dropdown option](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#options), and the `w-100` and `position-static` class in the dropdown to make it take up 100% of parent width.

```
<div class="container">
    <button class="dropdown-toggle btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown" data-display="static">
        dropdown
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu position-static w-100">
        <a href="" class="dropdown-item">one</a>
        <a href="" class="dropdown-item">two</a>
        <a href="" class="dropdown-item">three</a>
        <a href="" class="dropdown-item">four</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/5GjATutCBb

---

Also see: [How to make a Bootstrap 4 full width dropdown in Navbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49659305)

Answer (score -1):

You can add `min-width: 100%` to the `dropdown-menu` class