# How to fit dropdown in div bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am newer to Bootsrap 4 and I want to fit the dropdown in div.
I have written following code with Bootstrap 4 to implement the above but it doesn't work:

```
<div class="p-2 bg-info col-md-4">
     <div class="dropdown">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Dropdown
         </button>
         <div class="dropdown-menu">
               <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link
               2</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Bootstrap 4 `w-100` utility class on the `dropdown-menu`, and `btn-block` to make the button full width...

```
<div class="p-2 bg-info col-md-4">
     <div class="dropdown">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Dropdown
         </button>
         <div class="dropdown-menu w-100">
               <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link
               2</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/H1QUpWhQZD

---

Also see:
[How to make width of dropdown-menu equal to width of it's parent in bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52242706/how-to-make-width-of-dropdown-menu-equal-to-width-of-its-parent-in-bootstrap-4)
[How to make a Bootstrap 4 full width dropdown in Navbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49659305/how-to-make-a-bootstrap-4-full-width-dropdown-in-navbar/49659512#49659512)